# How to make work a paste functionality on click on my IIS server?

Tags: angular, clipboard, paste

I create an **Angular** application. I create a **.js file** in my **assets folder**, I create a function **on click** which will **paste** the last element of the **clipboard**. On localhost, it's work well but when I build my application and I test it I have this error and it doesn't work (it doesn't paste my word):

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'readText' of undefined

I create an example to show you how I did my function and how I use it:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b1f7ou

I use the same Chrome for the both test.

If you have an other solution for me to have a function on click which paste the last word of the clipboard, I take it.

Comment: Are you using a different browsers for development and live testing? Btw the stackblitz works for me on Chrome 74 but it fails, with a similar error as yours, on IE 11.

Comment: Hi, navigator.clipboard it's not compatible with IE, please read the next docu.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard#Browser_compatibility 

by this reason you'r getting this error

Comment: @F.G. I use the same browser ( Chrome )

Comment: Hi @Ztemps , I try on Firefox it should work but I have the error : navigator.clipboard

Comment: Can you further elaborate on what you mean by "build my application and I test it"? That might help.

Comment: @F.G. On angular when you want to have your application in a server you have to compile it the command is ng build. And for test it I just go on my application url and try to paste the last word of the clipboard on click. https://angular.io/cli/build